# openshift baremetal VS vm for production

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise, okd

Does it make sense to run open shift 3 / okd on bare metal or on virtual machines

- What would be the pros and cons of each?
- would it not affect overall performance if it runs on virtual machines?

Comment: This is essentially the same question as "What are the pros/cons of virtual machine over bare metal?" which is discussed extensively on the wider internet and is a little too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you had better to use virtual machine for efficient resource usage, and if you use cloud platform supported by OpenShift for using virtual machine, you can also use auto scaling through API.

In other hand, if you need to use GPU and CPU aggressively for some tasks, then you had better some host as bare metal.

You can mix/adjust above host machines as your system requirements either.

I hope it help you.